# Appending specific indices from zipped lists

Tags: python

I have been succesfull in filtering a list by appending the value of the list index if it's first three characters are digits. This filters out certain values, although the original list is connected to three other lists that need to be filtered in the same pattern. Thus I've been trying to zip the lists and filter them from there. Although I'm a new coder so I've met a dead end ability-wise. There are 4 input lists and an output (where I'll return a list of lists). Here's my code:

```
list0=IN[0]
list1=IN[1]
list2=IN[2]
list3=IN[3]

f_list=[]

for x in list0:
    if x[0:3].isdigit():
        f_list.append(x)
    else:
        continue

OUT=f_list
```

How do I make the matching values in list1, list2 and list3 filter in the same pattern as list0 filters to f_list?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What's not working? What does it do instead? Provide a minimal example of lists to try it out please.

Comment: @DonQuiKong The script shown is working in that it will return a list like so:

731 21  - 
502 72  - 
Alpha  - 
0B2 52  - 
184 11  - 

Into this:

731 21  - 
502 72  - 
184 11  - 

This is correct as only the lists with numbers only in the first 3 characters are returned. The code shown works.

Comment: @DonQuiKong
I just want to add a component that filters the lists 1, 2 and 3 in the same pattern like so:

list1: A1,B1,C1,D1  -
list2: A2,B2,C2,D2  -

If the first and third lists are removed in the filtering (list A1 and list C1), i want the corresponding indices removed in the other list (A2 and C2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do what you want like this using only standard Python means:

```
# initial sample data
IN = [['502', 'a503', '-5.1.0', 'qwe', '999', '1 1 1'],
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

# dictionary with the data we want to filter (single dictionary instead of 3 lists)
data_in = {idx: IN[idx] for idx in range(3)}
print(data_in)

# empty dictionary to store filtered data
data_out = {idx: list() for idx in data_in}

# processing
for pos, elem in enumerate(data_in[0]):
    # condition
    if elem[:3].isdigit():
        # if condition is true then we treat all the data in the dictionary
        for idx in data_in:
            data_out[idx].append(data_in[idx][pos])

print(data_out)
```

Output:

```
{0: ['502', 'a503', '-5.1.0', 'qwe', '999', '1 1 1'], 1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']}
{0: ['502', '999'], 1: [1, 5], 2: ['a', 'e']}
```

Problems like this can be solved with libraries like `pandas` much easier and more efficiently with literally couple lines of code.

Comment: Thank you, man. Appreciate it.
I've tried copying your code (exactly) and here's my result:
https://ibb.co/dpf9Bpn . The left side is the input. The output gives me a null value. Do i need to replace the idx with indices? Again, I've been coding for about a week so i don't comprehend that much coding in general. EDIT: I've obviously replaced my output with data_out

Comment: After replacing the output i got the correctly filtered list, but only the third (of the four). It has been filtered just as i want, but I only get that one list out. What should i change? My output is set:
    OUT: data_out[idx]

Comment: EDIT: I got your script to work. I simply put down multiple outputs. Whomp. Thank you again, Poolka.

Comment: @Ask The result is `data_out` which is dictionary containing lists. The first list is `data_out[0]`, the second is `data_out[1]`, and so on. If you want list containing lists you may change the processing code or do something like `OUT = [data_out[idx] for idx in range(3)]`. It depends on you.